# XLSB/XLSM files in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have some xlsm and xlsb files that I store in my data lake. 4 XLSB/ XLSM files are loaded in daily and I want to load these files into my data factory pipeline to process them.

I understand that data factory only reads in xlsx files. Currently, my approach is to convert the files outside of data factory before loading it in. However, as these files are quite big, converting to xlsx outside takes quite awhile.

However, I was wondering if there is anyway to convert it in data factory itself? Or if possible, is there a work around to directly use the xlsb and xlsm files in data factory?

Source: Folder in Data Lake storage gen 2
Destination: Output to another folder in Data lake

Comment: what is your source and destination?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula Ill be reading in the data from a folder in Data Lake and then outputting the data into a different folder in the same container in data lake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Binary datasets** for these kinds of files. Create Binary dataset for the source and sink of the ADLS gen2 and use copy activity.

These are my sample files:

[image]

In the source Binary dataset, give the file path till container in the dataset and use wild card path in the copy activity source(Now give the path till your folder) like below.

[image]

As you want these files to be copied daily, use **Schedule trigger** for the above pipeline and schedule it daily. And to get only the latest daily files, use the **Filter by last modified** in the copy activity source(Make sure to give this in UTC format and it should match your time zone).

Use `@adddays(utcNow(),-1)` for startdate and `@utcNow()` for the end date.
In the sink, just give the path till the target folder like below.

[image]

Now, execute the pipeline and your files will be copied to the destination folder like mine.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, if I want to perform some transformation on the data (extracting a sheet from the xlsb file etc), would this method work?

Comment: No, ADF dataflows do not support Binary files. Only copy activity supports binary files.

Comment: I have tried to convert the source files to `.xlsx` one by one in a loop by using copy activity(Binary datasets), even though the pipeline gets succeed it is giving a corrupt file in the target. So AFAIK, in ADF it might not be possible to convert the above type of files to excel files. It's better to build your programming logic for it and call the script from ADF. After converting to excel files, use excel dataset as source in Dataflow. If you use python language, you can use databricks and call the notebook from ADF.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!!