# Azure Data Factory - Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Good Day,

We have a requirement to select only specific files from a Gen2 Data lake and copy into another Gen2 Data lake using ADF in Azure Synapse and also need to copy only files containing the word "part" in the name. The data is in CSV format and it needs to be saved as CSV.

There will be 4 different file names types

_committed......
_started.....
_success.....
_part.....

Here we need to copy only _part..... files into a destination folder.

Any advice or tips on the dynamic selection(we have a solution but it does not work great)

We have tried different formats and converting with other tools and it works but it is not automated. That is why we are looking for a dynamic selection for files that contain "part".

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, use the Copy Activity and the wildcard path to set your matching file patterns
[image]

and to copy from 1 folder to another,you can use binary dataset:
[XLSB/XLSM files in Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77233852/xlsb-xlsm-files-in-azure-data-factory)